# Extracting three numbers from a string (missing number?)

Tags: r, regex

I've been profiting from SO, quite a while now and now decided to sign up and try to a) help others and b) get help from great guys :)

So coming to my question, I have vector extracted from a data frame that looks like this (just little subset of the data):

```
cho <- c("[M-H]: C4H4O2", 
"[M+Hac-H]: C5H10O6",
"[M-H]: C6H4O3",
"[M+Fa-H]: C7H6O",
"[M-H]: C9H8O3",
"[M-H]: C18H30O3);
```

Now from this vector I want to extract the numbers in order to get the number of "C", "H", and "O" atoms:

```
temp <- strsplit(cho, "[^[:digit:]]");
temp <- as.numeric(unlist(temp));

#remove NAs
temp <- temp[!is.na(temp)];

#split into three column matrix and convert to df to merge with original df
temp <- as.data.frame(matrix(temp, ncol = 3, byrow = T));
```

In this case R is recycling the data to generate the matrix, in my case for the bigger data set, the generated `temp` vector is long enough and the matrix is getting generated, but it is a mess; this is due to cases such as `"[M+Fa-H]: C7H6O"` where only two numbers can be extracted; how is it possible to get a "1" after an "O" so that three numbers can be extracted instead of two? Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_extract_all`.  Use the regex lookaround to match one or more numbers (`\\d+`) that follows either a `C` or `H` or `O`, extract those numbers in a `list`, and convert to `integer`

```
library(stringr)
lst <- lapply(str_extract_all(cho, "(?<=C|H|O)\\d+"), as.integer)
```

---

Or a `base R` option is

```
read.csv(text=sub(".*C?(\\d+)H?(\\d+)O?(\\d*).*", 
              "\\1,\\2,\\3", cho), header=FALSE, fill=TRUE)
```

Comment: great! also wherever value is missing, we might need to insert 1

Comment: also could you explain the regex used step-by-step

Comment: Much shorter code than mine, thanks a lot! `base R` solution is perfect for me, only NAs to be replace!